# Effect of using PHP mail()

Tags: php, sendmail

I've got a project where by I send email using PHP's inbuilt mail() function, I'm only sending one email at a time with a small amount of HTML and very limited CSS (two tables and a little CSS in the head for styling), but the server seems to be doing it really slowly (so much so that the page upon which an admin sends the email frequently times out)

So my question is this; does mail() put a high workload on the server (not sure if that is the right term) or is it just that the server I'm using is rubbish?

Is it worth me looking into projects like http://pear.php.net/package/Mail for this kind of thing?

EDIT:

Here is the code in question:

```
    $query = "SELECT email FROM $a_table WHERE id='$Id'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed: ".mysql_error());

    $mail_to = mysql_fetch_row($result); 
    $mail_to = $mail_to[0];

    // multiple recipients
    $to  = $mail_to;
    // subject
    $subject = 'notification';

    // message
    $message = '<html>
    <head>
      <title>title goes here</title>
      <style type="text/css">
        table { border: 1px solid #000;}
        table tr th { background-color: #d8d8d8; border-bottom: 1px solid #000}
        table tr th, table tr td { padding: 4px; text-align: center; }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
          <h1>header goes here</h1>
          <table cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <th>th1</th><td>'.$var.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>th2</th><td>'.$var2.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>th3</th><td>'.$var3.'</td>
            </tr>
          </table>

          <p>&nbsp;</p>

          <table cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="13">Key</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>G</th>
                <th>I</th>
                <th>L</th>
                <th>M</th>
                <th>N</th>
                <th>O</th>
                <th>Q</th>
                <th>R</th>
                <th>S</th>
                <th>V</th>
                <th>W</th>
                <th>C</th>
                <th>?</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>G</td>
                <td>I</td>
                <td>L</td>
                <td>M</td>
                <td>U</td>
                <td>O</td>
                <td>Q</td>
                <td>R</td>
                <td>S</td>
                <td>V</td>
                <td>W</td>
                <td>C</td>
                <td>R</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>


    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";


    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'From: admin<admin@admin.com>' . "\r\n"; // might need to get rid of this soon

    // Mail it
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
```

Comment: Could you post some code? It's not common for mail() to timeout a page, it's probably something else

Comment: It is always worth using somebody else's well tested work for anything like this. I use [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), I see a lot of people recommend [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/), I have seen several people abuse PEAR::Mail although I haven't used it enough to comment. Sending an email should take a matter of seconds (possibly less than one) so if your requests are timing out something else is going on here. Even a poorly set up server should not have any problem with this in terms of system resources, it's likely a network problem, or unrelated to the mail entirely.

Comment: what about PHP Mailer: http://phpmailer.worxware.com

Comment: `mail()` is a fire-and-forget mechanism. It write to mail spool directory and continue the script's proses. The written mail is later processed by MTA: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent Therefore, if you have timeout problem, big possibility that it is caused by something else.

Comment: Do not use stylesheet when sending html e-mails. Use only inline styleing. More info here http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: I haven't included a stylehseet, the style is inline and in the head of the document.

Comment: @silent That is not true on every platform, on Windoze you have to wait for the mail to send because it does not pass it off to sendmail.

Comment: just added the code in; hope that helps

Comment: @SeanDunwoody I don't see any `mail()` calls in that code... Or indeed any PHP...

Comment: @DaveRandom whoops, only copied in the content of the message to be sent *facepalm*

Comment: copied in the relevant code that I missed

Comment: Also, not sure if this is relevant but when I access PHPMyAdmin for this site it is incredibly slow, I'm talking about waiting 10 or more seconds to perform simple tasks using it.

Comment: saying that I haven't had any speed problems reading or writing to the database so far with PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mail()` function is usually very fast. I've used it in the past for mass email systems and that was processing hundreds of emails per second.

I'd recommend checking how your system is configured to send email. `mail()` generally utilizes your system's sendmail install (or postfix). You should think about checking the logs to see if there is an problem there.