# PHP mail hangs indefinitely - How to debug?

Tags: php, email, pear

I've set up a simple mail system, which resembles the following:

```
$from = 'me <me@me.com>';
$to = 'you <you@you.com>';
$subject = 'subject';
$body = 'body';

$host = 'www.me.com';
$headers = array('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);

$smtp = Mail::Factory('smtp', array('host' => $host, 'auth' => true,
                      'username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password'));
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    throw new Exception('emailException');
}
```

When I try run the script however the browser (chrome) hangs indefinately. There is no exception thrown, no error page shown by the browser, it just sits and waits for a response (for over 12 minutes, longest I've left it).

My actual program is slightly different (the code is enclosed in a function with info passed as parameters). I have used static debugging and confirmed that the parameters getting passed in are correct, however it just never errors, so I can't even test any error information in $mail.

Does anyone know how I should go about debugging this?

**Update** I can confirm the page hangs when calling $smtp->send(...)

Comment: This sounds very similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063517/effect-of-using-php-mail

Comment: Can you confirm that the problem persists with this testcase? Your "actual program" isn't strictly relevant.

Comment: Er, also, I see no call to `mail()` here.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging this could be done in the logfiles, there you might find some PEAR errors.

Futhermore you could debug by echo statements between each line of code so you know exactly where it hangs.

Long delays are likely to incur when trying to connect to a non existing host. So that's where I would start searching although 12 minutes is very very long. You need to use the PEAR class because you need to send through a designated SMTP server?

Comment: Yes, I'm sending through a designated smtp server. I'm new to PHP and this is literally all I've done with PEAR, do you know where the log files are located? (i'm using ubuntu)

Comment: Would take a look at: /var/log/apache2/ when you are using a normal install but it might also be stored somewhere else, all in configurable so take a look in your config otherwise.

Comment: Ok i'll check that now, I can confirm it hangs on the $smtp->send()

Comment: Ok, take a normal mail client (outlook/Mail/whatever) and try to use this SMTP server with exactly your settings. So you can confirm that the SMTP server is totally right, working etc. Be very secure with the security settings, so make sure they are exactly the same as you use with this PEAR class. Some mail clients detect them automatically, you want an exact replica to test.

Answer (score 0):

IME, more than 99% of reported errors regarding PHP's mail functionality are problems with mail and neither PHP nor it's interface.

Why are you trying to connect directly to the server instead of using PHP's mail()?

Do you have shell access to the machine? It makes the following simpler however you can do these from PHP.

Can you resolve the smtp server hostname?

Can you connect to port 25 on the smtp server?

How is authentication implemented? (should be included in the [response to your EHLO](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/smtp-commands-reference-auth.htm))

If you've got shell access then route the connection via a logging proxy or capture usnig tcpdump/wireshark and see where the connection is getting stuck.

Most likely the mailserver is not implementing proper SMTP and the authentication is going awry.